# sqlalchemy.exc.NoReferencedTableError on many to one relationship

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I am trying to create a table with entries that reference a second table entry (many to one relationship) using sqlalchemy but I am getting this error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.NoReferencedTableError: Foreign key associated with column 'query_results.ontology_name' could not find table 'OntologyVersion' with which to generate a foreign key to target column 'name'
```

Here is my code:

```
class OntologyVersion(Base):  
    __tablename__ = 'ontology_version'
    name = Column(String, primary_key=True)
    version = Column(String, primary_key=True)
    children = relationship('QueryResultAssertion')
class QueryResultAssertion(Base): 
    __tablename__ = 'query_results'
    node_id = Column(String)
    ontology_name = Column(String, ForeignKey('ontology_version.name'))
    ontology_version = Column(String, ForeignKey('ontology_version.version'))
    # Separate ontology version into its own table to keep database
    # smaller
    __table_args__ = (
       ForeignKeyConstraint(
           ['ontology_name', 'ontology_version'],
           ['OntologyVersion.name', 'OntologyVersion.version'],
          ),
    )

Session = sessionmaker()
# create the engine
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:', echo=True)
# associate it with our custom Session class
Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)
```

What am I doing wrong here? 
Your help would be really appreciated!

Comment: `ForeignKeyConstraint` should reference the underlying `Table`, not the model, so `ontology_version.name`.

Comment: That solve that error but now I am getting 
sqlalchemy.exc.AmbiguousForeignKeysError: Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship OntologyVersion.children - there are multiple foreign key paths linking the tables.  Specify the 'foreign_keys' argument, providing a list of those columns which should be counted as containing a foreign key reference to the parent table.

Comment: Didn't notice the separate `ForeignKey` definitions on the columns before, are those really needed? They do not seem to reference actual keys, because `ontology_version` name and version alone are not unique (together they form the primary key).

Comment: This is what is confusing for me as I don't understand in which variable is the foreign key stored on the QueryResultAssertion. I just want a column that points to the foreignKey

Comment: In this case the `__table_args__` approach is the correct one, because you are referencing a composite key. The `ForeignKey` construct passed to a `Column` is only able to reference a single column key. This is pretty similar to how it works in SQL as well; as a shorthand you can define on column level that it references another table's key, but composite key references have to be defined on table level.